# Kickstart does not add repos

Tags: centos, kickstart

I have a kickstart file I am trying to use for CentOS 7.4 installations. It works well, but it does not add the requested repos. I've run through this a few times and I'm sure it basically skips over the step for adding repos. Here is what it looks like:

```
url --url http://<my_IP>/centos71
lang en_US.UTF-8

keyboard us

timezone --utc America/New_York

network --onboot yes --device em1 --bootproto dhcp --noipv6

firewall --disabled
selinux --disabled
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512

rootpw  --iscrypted <encrypted_pass>

clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=xvda

zerombr

part /boot --fstype=ext4 --asprimary --size=200 --ondisk=xvda
part pv.1 --asprimary --grow --size=10000 --ondisk=xvda
volgroup vg0 --pesize=4096 pv.1
logvol / --fstype=ext4 --name=lv_root --vgname=vg0 --size=9000
logvol swap --name=lv_swap --vgname=vg0 --size=512

bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=xvda --append="crashkernel=auto"

reboot
repo --name="CentOS" --baseurl="http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/"
repo --name="DockerCE" --baseurl="https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/"

%packages
@base
@core
gcc
gcc-c++
git
net-snmp
nfs-utils
screen
vim
tree
yum-utils
device-mapper-persistent-data
lvm2
%end

....
```

When the installation completes, I check /etc/yum.repos.d/ and none of the repos are there. Is there something that I may be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`repo` directive](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax) is only used for the installation step of anaconda installer.  The repositories have to be configured during post-installation. That is, the repos you're specifying are configured for use during the installation step of the system, but not transferred over once the installation is complete.

Consider using a solution like [Installing YUM repositories that are specified in Kickstart file](https://serverfault.com/questions/315313/installing-yum-repositories-that-are-specified-in-kickstart-file).

> In the post section of your kickstart include something like this:
>
> ```
> %post
> cat >/etc/yum.repos.d/your.repo <<EOF
> [... INCLUDE REPO CONFIG FILE CONTENTS HERE ...]
> EOF
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You could try the `--install` flag, which should make your repos available post install, for example

```
repo --install --name="DockerCE" --baseurl="https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/"
```

[Link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax) to more documentation. Search for the section "repo".